# Should dating couples who put themselves regularly to the occasion of sin be granted absolution if they do not have a will to avoid such situations?

Tags: catholicism, marriage, morality

**Definitions.** dating couple = (young) man and (young) women who have a boyfriend-girlfriend relationship between them.

**Question.** Should dating couple which regularly (or just without any good reason) put themselves in a situation where they are alone (and therefore exposed to the occasion of sin, for example, girlfriend visiting a boyfriend in his home when there is no one else with them) be granted absolution in the confession if they do not have a will to stop avoiding such situations?

**Why it seems that they should be able to receive absolution.**

1. The couple may say (if they already fell into the sin once): "We are sorry for our sin against the 6th commandment of God, however, that situation was not the cause of our sin, but our evil desires were. Therefore there is no need to avoid the situation but we will just fix our desires. Therefore, since that situation was not essential to our sin, why should we suffer not receiving absolution for it, if we are contrite for that which was essential to our sin, namely, for our evil desires?"
2. The couple may say: Why should we avoid such situations, when that situation can bring us some good which otherwise we would not be able to achieve, for example, we can study together and easier come to the knowledge of some subject?
3. In today's practice, the Church does not deny absolution.

**Why it seems that they should not be able to receive absolution.**

Saint Alphonsus Liguori says (in [*Praxis confessarii*](https://books.google.com/books?id=MTGVcgx0zEIC&printsec=frontcover&hl=hr&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) t.64-65):

> Adunt aliqui doctores negandam quoque absolutionem illi qui occasionem
>   externam non removet, si cum occasione coniungitur habitus vitiosus,
>   aut magna tentatio, seu vehemens passio, quamvis usque tunc in ea
>   occasione nunquam peccaverit; nam facile deinde peccare poterit, si ab
>   occasione se non amoverit... Et hic caveant confessarii a permittendo
>   sponsis domos sponsarum adire et puellis earumque parentibus sponsos
>   in domum admittere, quia raro aut evenit quod tales sponsi non
>   labantur, saltem in verba aut cogitationes turpes in huiusmodi
>   occasione, dum omnes aspectus et colloquia inter sponsos sunt
>   incentiva ad peccandum: estque moraliter impossibile ipsos invicem
>   conversari et non sentire stimulos ad eos turpes actos... Generaliter
>   autem loquendo de adolescentibus et puellis qui invicem se adamant,
>   quippe non sunt isti omnes indistincte de gravi culpa damnandi, sed
>   ordinarie puto ipsos difficulter esse extra occasionem proximam
>   lethaliter peccandi. Id nimium experientia patet: nam ex centum
>   adolescentibus vix duo aut tres in occasione a mortalibus invenientur
>   immunes; et si non in principio, saltem in progressu, tales enim
>   adamantes prius conversantur invicem ob propensionem, deinde propensio
>   fit passio postquam radicem in corde fixerit, mentem obtenebrat et eos
>   in mille rimina ruere facit. Hinc cardinalis Picus de Mirandula,
>   episcopus albanensis, in sua dioecesi per edictum suos admonuit
>   confessores, ne tales adamantes absolverent su postquam ter ab aliis
>   iam fuerint admoniti ab huiusmodi amore sectando non abstinuissent...

What follow is not a translation, but an attempt of a translation (it is now even wholly done from the Latin, so if there is an obvious mistake, please feel free to suggest correct translation):

> Some Church Doctors add that absolution should be denied to one who
>   does not remove the external occasion of sin if with the occasion
>   there exists vicious habit or great temptation or furious passion,
>   even if the sin was not committed in a such a situation. One would
>   easily be able to sin if he does not move from such an occasion... And
>   here let the confessors take care that they do not allow finances into
>   house of fiancee; and to girls and their parents that they do not
>   allow finances into their house, because it rarely happens that the
>   fiancés do not fall into sin in such occasion, at least in words or in
>   shameful thoughts; because every look and conversation between fiancés
>   is a boost to sin, and morally it is impossible that two of them are
>   spending time (hang out) together and that they do not feel impelled
>   to those shameful acts... Generally speaking about boys and girls who
>   are in love, not all of them without difference is for condemnation
>   for mortal sin, but I think that they can hardly be outside of
>   occasion to sin. That is manifest by experience; namely, out of a
>   hundred young boys and girls, bearly two or three in that situation
>   remain untouched by mortal sin. Even if not in the beginning, but as
>   time passes, such lovers will spend time together because of sympathy,
>   then sympathy will grow into a passion, and when it takes root in the
>   heart, darkens the mind, and lead them to fall through thousands of
>   cracks. For these reasons, cardinal Pico della Mirandola, bishop of
>   Albanians, in his diocese made an edict with which he encouraged his
>   confessors, that such lovers should not be given absolution, if they,
>   after being three times warned by others, do not move from following
>   such love...

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved by a translation of the Latin.

Comment: As the question is phrased, it would also help if you backed up your assumption that being alone is **necessarily** a near occasion of sin.

Comment: citation needed for "In today's practice, the Church does not deny absolution"

Comment: BTW, [Cardinal Lodovico Pico della Mirandola](http://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/bishop/bpidmi.html) is not to be confused with the [humanist Giovanni Pico della Mirandola](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pico-della-mirandola/), who was philosopher-physicist/dynamicist and a precursor of sorts to Galileo; cf. pp. 85-88 (PDF pp. 103-106) of [Duhem](https://www.encyclopedia.com/people/history/historians-miscellaneous-biographies/pierre-maurice-marie-duhem#block-views-block-article-topic-articles-block)'s [_Galileo's Precursors_](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6854).

Comment: "_that situation [=occasion of sin] was not the cause of our sin, but our evil desires were_" is a lie because voluntarily placing oneself in an occasion of sin is sin, and sin corrupts the will/desires.

Comment: Can you be clearer about whether they're having sex or not?

Comment: @Thom you won't find one because it isn't a special case. Absolution is granted if the penitent seems truly repentant for the sins and would only be withheld if if were apparent they were not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *couple which regularly […] put themselves in a situation where they are alone*

A non-married man and woman cohabiting is called [concubinage](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=32696) (≢fornication).

Cardinal Cajetan, O.P., in his penitential manual [*Summula de peccatis* pp. 51](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_9tkDWQsoOkIC/page/n82)-52, concisely defines concubinage and how one is to repent of it:

> *The vice of concubinage is to be detested, & why.*
> The vice of concubinage does not only include the mortal sin of fornication, but the state of mortal sin is added to it. And therefore to be truly repentant of this sin, the omission not only of carnal acts but also the departure from such a state is required.
>
> <sup>*Vitium concubinatus detestandum, & quare.*
> Concubinatus non solum includit peccatum mortale fornicationis, se addit statum peccati mortalis. Et propterea ad sui veram pœnitentiam exigit non solum omissionem actus carnalis, sed recessum a tali statu.</sup>

Even in English, "[to live in [a state of] sin](https://oed.com/view/Entry/180030#eid22549695)" means "to cohabit outside marriage".

Comment: I think this answer could benefit from an "in conclusion". It doesn't really address the main question unless you read into it a bit.

Comment: The OP is not specifically asking about the state of manifest sin (cohabitating) but a relationship with accompanying occasions of sin